# Is there any known api or connectivity to Twitter Vine?

Tags: twitter, vine

Either via its own api or via the twitter api?

There are a couple of apps: http://www.vineroulette.com/ and http://vinepeek.com/ has anyone got an idea of how they get the vine feeds?

Comment: @AndrewBarber Wouldn't `twitter-vine` would be more consistent? (I'm thinking of the `twitter-bootstrap` tag). Also I fear people will just use `vine` and I wonder if it wouldn't be better just to let it stand on it's own as there is not a conflict like the one in `bootstrap`.

Comment: @madth3 It would, yes; but I don't think I can create a `twitter-vine` when there is a `twittervine` tag. Lemme try now! UPDATE: Nope; it told me I can't because `twittervine` already exists. (I didn't create that one)

Comment: @AndrewBarber I think `vine` is better. We didn't create a tag called `facebook-instagram` he? :)

Comment: After a quick research and many referances are liked to this question: https://github.com/starlock/vino/wiki/API-Reference explanes the (inofficial?!) API

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Well, not for the moment according to some requests inside the twitter support: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/14721

The only things I can find right now is the card used inside a tweet. For example: http://vine.co/v/bwBYItOUKrw/card

### My own search

I took some times so see what kind of request does Vine on iOS, using Charles.

First, I checked Tweetbot to see how it retrieve the Vine preview image for its feed. A simple `GET` on the Vine video to retrieve header metas and get the preview:

```
<meta property="twitter:image" content="https://vines.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbs/8800194F-D323-40F2-8AD2-7C19EA2505A3-3974-000000D33D0303AB_1.0.6.mp4.jpg?versionId=PZAXllJkKvo4FGk47Mb4JfM7yADdF5eC">
```

Which is:

[image]

In same meta, you can retrieve the video stream:

```
<meta property="twitter:player:stream" content="https://vines.s3.amazonaws.com/videos/8800194F-D323-40F2-8AD2-7C19EA2505A3-3974-000000D33D0303AB_1.0.6.mp4?versionId=gqt.N2z3cdss2nzFam5zam4QR9sje_vC">
```

Then I opened Vine app. And it makes a request to `https://api.vineapp.com/`. Since everything is send though `https`, I can only see the request / response encrypted.

### Something more interesting

With the api url, I searched on Google and find interesting stuff ! One guy [dig better inside Vine](http://www.gironda.org/2013/02/25/digging-in-the-vineyard-part-1.html) request by acting as a man in a middle to see the real request url. There are 3 articles. At the end, the guy successfully posted a video on Vine using its own client.

After that, I checked on Github and found one [*non-official* Vine API](https://github.com/starlock/vino/wiki/API-Reference) using Python. People seems to use the work from the previous guy to determine API full url.

And here is a [built-in interface in PHP](https://github.com/FaridW/Vine) of this non-official API.

I think you have enough stuff to start your own VineRoulette :)

Comment: As of around Oct 24th, these private API hacks no longer work.